# Icon not showing in PyQt application exe when built using cx_Freeze

Tags: image, icons, pyqt, cx-freeze

I know this has been asked a bunch of times in this forum, but I really can't get my application icon to work when I build my PyQt application into a working exe-file using cx_Freeze.

I have copied the Qt image plugins (qico4.dll, qjpeg4.dll, etc.) into appdir/imageformats and also into appdir. I copied qt.conf to those dirs too. Changed the paths to it and nothing. This was suggested in some topic.

I tried to set the icon-option in a number of ways with setup.py-file and also without it.

I tried to create a resource file using qt designer and convert it. I tried to set the icon using qt designer to my mainwindow. Still nothing.

This is now my setup.py script:

```
import sys

from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [
    Executable(
        "main.py",
        base = base,
        icon = "icon_64x64.ico",
        appendScriptToExe = True,
        appendScriptToLibrary = False,
        targetName = "MyApp.exe")
]

buildOptions = dict(
    create_shared_zip = False)

setup(
    name = "MyApp",
    version = "1.0",
    options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
    executables = executables)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application icon isn't something Qt manages - it's embedded into the exe file for the operating system to read.

Check that `icon_64x64.ico` exists in the same folder that you're running `setup.py` from, and that it's a valid ico file. For comparison, [here's](https://bitbucket.org/taxonome/taxonome/src/7ff0fa8bdc8eeac3d1e03362f8671a870d1dc4db/freeze_gui.py) a setup.py that works with an icon.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After doing those things, I finally realized the problem... The icon worked the whole time, I just did not realize the application icon is not the same as my mainwindow icon... Well, live and learn, I guess =)

Comment: The link is dead. Do you still have the example?

Comment: Updated the link. The mercurial repository had to be converted to git.